# Looping through a multi-variable subset

Tags: r, loops, subset

I have a large data frame that I want to subset by the year and ID, so I can plot each separate ID for individual years.
This is my latest attempt, but it only outputs one year and one ID:

```
yearloop<-unique(set$year)                 
for(m in 1:length(yearloop)){
  set_1<-subset(set,year==yearloop[m])
  IDloop<-unique(unlist(set_1$ID))
  for(c in 1:length(IDloop)){
    set_2<-subset(set_1,ID==IDloop[c])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
split(mtcars, list(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am))
```

Or with you data: `split(set, list(set$year,set$id))`

If you need to plot for different subsets of your dataframe you might not even need to split your data, you could as well use ggplot and facet your plots, like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + facet_grid (~ vs + am)
```